# How do you configure the request throttling delay for kops?

Tags: kops

Kops by default will back-off for 6 seconds when it gets rate limited by AWS:

```
retry_handler.go:55] Inserting delay before AWS request (ec2::DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions) to avoid RequestLimitExceeded: 6s
```

This often isn't enough, and we will continually get rate limit errors on any operation:

```
Got RequestLimitExceeded error on AWS request (ec2::DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions)
```

Is there a way to configure this behaviour? Can we set the delay?

Answer (score 1):

not that i found, pretty sure its hard coded, however you can request the raise the limits from AWS support, they are usually ok with it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, kOps have rewritten how launch templates are being discovered, which significantly reduces the amount of `DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions` made. In most cases, you should no longer see these warnings using newer kOps versions.